# arp-requests cannot be seen by specific nodes

Tags: linux, networking, wifi, linux-networking, arp

I create an open ad-hoc wlan by using `iwconfig` (I have the same issue with `wpa_supplicant` as well). there are 4 nodes on the network as seen on the figure below. The nodes run ubuntu 12.04 and debian squeeze, and have 3.7.1, 3.5 and 3.2 kernels. I use two different usb dongle brands (TP link and ZCN) that all have AR9271 chipset and `ath9k_htc` driver (here is [lsusb output](http://pastebin.com/bfeGfbp0) and [ethtool output](http://pastebin.com/K8LMaciz)).

The problem I am experiencing is that two nodes (`10.0.0.2` and `10.0.0.5`) which have TP link usb wifi dongles can ping any node on the network, and vice-versa. However, the other nodes (`10.0.0.6` and `10.0.0.7`) that have ZCN wifi dongle cannot ping each other, but they have no problem communicating with TP-link wifi modules. `tcpdump` shows that `10.0.0.6` and `10.0.0.7` cannot see their arp-request, e.g.

```
20:37:52.470305 ARP, Request who-has 10.0.0.7 tell 10.0.0.6, length 28
20:37:53.463713 ARP, Request who-has 10.0.0.7 tell 10.0.0.6, length 28
20:37:54.463622 ARP, Request who-has 10.0.0.7 tell 10.0.0.6, length 28
20:37:55.472868 ARP, Request who-has 10.0.0.7 tell 10.0.0.6, length 28
20:37:56.463439 ARP, Request who-has 10.0.0.7 tell 10.0.0.6, length 28
20:37:57.463469 ARP, Request who-has 10.0.0.7 tell 10.0.0.6, length 28
```

but they are able to see and get reply from TP-link's modules.

```
20:39:23.634459 ARP, Request who-has 10.0.0.2 tell 10.0.0.6, length 28
20:39:23.634551 ARP, Reply 10.0.0.2 is-at 64:70:02:18:d4:6a (oui Unknown), length 28
20:39:23.636687 IP 10.0.0.6 > 10.0.0.2: ICMP echo request, id 572, seq 1, length 64
20:39:23.636809 IP 10.0.0.2 > 10.0.0.6: ICMP echo reply, id 572, seq 1, length 64
20:39:24.635497 IP 10.0.0.6 > 10.0.0.2: ICMP echo request, id 572, seq 2, length 64
20:39:24.635558 IP 10.0.0.2 > 10.0.0.6: ICMP echo reply, id 572, seq 2, length 64
20:39:28.651946 ARP, Request who-has 10.0.0.6 tell 10.0.0.2, length 28
20:39:28.654021 ARP, Reply 10.0.0.6 is-at 00:19:70:94:7c:8b (oui Unknown), length 28
```

My question is that what could be the reason that `10.0.0.6` and `10.0.0.7` cannot see the `arp-request` that they send each other? How can I find out the problem?

If I add couple more nodes with ZCN wifi dongle on the network, these nodes are also not able to talk with each other, but they are fine with TP-link. Or if I swap the wifi modules, the nodes with ZCN have always problem but TP-link modules are fine. 
[image]

[here](http://pastebin.com/QPCTntC4) is the `/etc/network/interfaces`, `ifconfig`, `iwconfig`, `ip a`, `ip r`, `route` outputs

EDIT: I was suspecting if the problem is `arp_filter` related but `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/*/arp_filter` is `0` on the all subdomains(*). If I add arp info of `10.0.0.6` and `10.0.0.7` manually on these nodes, `tcpdump` and `wireshark` does not show that they send `ping` to each other. If I `ping` the broadcast address (10.0.0.255 in my case), `10.0.0.6` and `10.0.0.7` are able hear it.

EDIT2: Here is pcap files http://filebin.net/6cle9a5iae from `10.0.0.6` (ZCN module), `10.0.0.7` (ZCN module), and `10.0.0.5` (TP-link module that does not have problem). here is the ping outputs from `10.0.0.6` http://pastebin.com/swFP2CJ9 I captured the packages simultaneously. The link also includes `ifconfig`; `iwconfig`; and `uname- a` outputs for each node.

Comment: Can you make a network capture of the ARP traffic on both 10.0.0.6 and 10.0.0.7 machines at the same time? Use tcp dump and share it as a pcap file.

Comment: Thank you Mircea Vutcovici, please see the EDIT2 for the pcap files. Please let me know if you would like to have more information.

Comment: Well, you can try using static ARP and see how/if it changes the connectivity problem.

Comment: Could you post a dump of the traffic from a wireless sniffer tool like `kismet`?  This will include the 802.11 headers in case there's something odd about them.

Comment: poige, I did add static ARP on the nodes but the problem remained.

Comment: Flup, I have not used kismet before, but I will try to figure out how to use it. Do you prefer any specific format or flag on kismet capturing?

Comment: It's a wee while since I've used it, but you should be able to get it to write a pcap file, then read that file with wireshark and post the results.

Comment: given the issues you are having with the ZCN dongles, and your requirement to have the clients all talk directly to each other on the network I would just throw them out and replace with the TPLink dongles that actually work on your network. Or it could be a driver issue with the ZCN adapters - try another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem recently. I figured out that AR9271 chipset's have problem on onboard transmitter antenna. If you use an external antenna, then you will not have a problem. And this problem only occurs on ad-hoc mode.

The reason you don't experience problem with the TP-link should be that these modules uses external antenna which overcomes the chipset's problem, and ZCN modules should not have an external antenna.

Answer (score 1):

This could be related to the "[hidden node problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_node_problem)" if .6 and .7 aren't in direct radio contact, but without knowing the distances involved it's impossible to say.

Also either or both of the chipsets could have a buggy ad-hoc mode, it's not used much these days and wouldn't be surprising.